# Does Keras Reshape maintain data structure and order through multiple reshape layers to and fro?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reshape

I am relying on multiple layers of Keras Reshape but have no ability to check that they are working together properly. I start with a preprocessed tensor of (BatchSize, 50, 100, 300). Where 5 news articles a day for 10 days (50) are represented by 100 words, with each word being represented by a 300-dimensional embedded vector.

I reshape this structure to and fro multiple times to get the data to fit with the various layers I am using. For example, I reshape (BatchSize, 50, 100, 300) to (BatchSize, 5000, 300) in order to feed the 300-dimensional word vectors through a time distributed layer, as to encode each word seperately. I then reshape the resulting (BatchSize, 5000, 10) to (BatchSize, 50, 100, 10). In this case, have I destroyed the relationship between the 50 News articles and their 100 words? Or does Reshape take care of this?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape

I looked into the documentation but couldn't really find an answer. I also searched through stack overflow. I am starting to think this is something everyone assumes is True (and probably is), but I need to be 100% sure.

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Reshape
from keras.models import Model

newsInput = Input(shape=(input_length, 100, 300))

#News Input pathway

#Reshape intp a format which TimeDistributed will accept. (flatten the layers I want to keep seperate)
newsInput2 = Reshape([input_length*100, 300])(newsInput)
#Encode each word from a 300 dimensional vector to a 10 dimensional vector.
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(10, input_shape=(300,), activation='tanh'), input_shape=(input_length*100, 300))(newsInput2)
print("x shape", x.shape)

#Reshape intp a format which TimeDistributed will accept. (flatten the layers I want to keep seperate)
x = Reshape([input_length, 100, 10])(x)
x = Reshape([input_length, 100*10])(x)
#encode each news article into a 10 dimensional vector.
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(10, input_shape=(1000,), activation='tanh'), input_shape=(input_length, 1000))(x)
# output = TimeDistributed(LSTM(10, return_sequences= False, input_shape=(100, 10), activation='tanh'), input_shape=(input_length, 100, 10))(x)
print("x", x.shape)

output = LSTM(10, activation="relu", input_shape=(50, 10))(x)

model = Model(inputs=newsInput, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

I got it to run without any errors. But still not sure if the multiple reshapes maintained data integratory.

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 50, 100, 300)      0

---

reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 5000, 300)         0

---

time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 5000, 10)          3010

---

reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 50, 100, 10)       0

---

reshape_3 (Reshape)          (None, 50, 1000)          0

---

time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 50, 10)            10010

---

## lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 10)                840

Total params: 13,860
Trainable params: 13,860
Non-trainable params: 0

---